# How to arrange gui elements (textboxes, lables..etc) with C# in Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, compact-framework

How to systematically arrange gui elements? (especially with config control, not hard coded).

This example of how my window form looks:

```
PanelName1

FirstName ______
LastName _______
Addresss _______
....etc
```

I would like to be able to arrange all available gui elements (FirstName, LastName, Address) in random order or possibly without having to knowing their names (just knowing that I have 10 fields in that windows form)? What can I possibly do to achieve this?

From what I tried upto now seems to be very messy and not that flexible.

I can generate a list of default locations (for example array which will have default Y location for 1st fields, 2nd fields.. etc). Can I iterate though all text boxes/labels (especially those which are visible) on the form and apply those coordinates based on arrangement control array which I can generate?

Arrangement array might have contain something like this `[2, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 0... etc]` meaning:

1st field assigns default  Y location of 2nd field

2nd filed assigns default Y location of 8th field.. etc

Comment: I think more information might be needed.  First, is this using WinForms, WPF etc...  There are some controls that can help with GUI arrangement such as TableLayoutPanel and FlowControlPanel.  Are you looking for something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

We'll I might suggest creating a user control.  The user control would have methods such as AddBox(TextBox textBox) or maybe AddBox(string label, TextBox textBox).

You would then keep track of the controls as they are added during execution time with a collection.

You can do a Dictionary so that you can pull the textbox by the label you gave it.

Try something like this.  This was built quickly so it is only meant to get you started.  You need to implement the error checking and proper collection handling.

```
    public partial class CustomForm : UserControl
{
    public CustomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel);
        flowLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        Forms = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
    }

    private FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel;


    private Dictionary<string, TextBox> Forms;

    public void AddForm(string label, TextBox textBox)
    {
        Forms.Add(label, textBox);
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        flp.Controls.Add(new Label {Text = label, AutoSize = true});
        flp.Controls.Add(textBox);
        flp.AutoSize = true;
        panel.Controls.Add(flp);
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
    }

    public string GetTextBoxValue(string label)
    {
        return Forms.ContainsKey(label) ? Forms[label].Text : "";
    }
    public void SetTextBoxValue(string label, string value)
    {
        if (Forms.ContainsKey(label))
        {
            Forms[label].Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```